# Secure password approach

Tags: security, authentication

I've to create a rest server with a users table for a login purpose. Mobile device will connect to this server for user login.
I would like to create a secure system and I thinked about this solution:

**USERS TABLE:**

- **PasswordHash** - CHAR(64) *for store the SHA256(password)*
- **PasswordToken** - CHAR(25) *for store a random possibly unique token*

**USER REGISTRATION:**

- The device will generate the SHA256 of the password provided by the user;
- The hash will be sent to the server through SSL;
- The server will store this hash in **PasswordHash** field and a random token in **PasswordToken** field;

**USER LOGIN:**

- The device will generate the SHA256 of the password provided by the user[*passwordDevice*];
- The server will generate a SHA512 of (**PasswordHash** + **PasswordToken**) [*hashServer*];
- The server will generate a SHA512 of (**passwordDevice** + **PasswordToken**) [*hashDevice*];
- The server will generate a BCrypt String of (**hashServer** + **serverSideKey**) [*bCryptServer*];
- The server will generate a BCrypt String of (**hashDevice** + **serverSideKey**) [*bCryptDevice*];

  ```
  if (bCryptServer == bCryptDevice) 
     LOGIN OK;
  else
     LOGIN REFUSED;
  ```

So, is this approach the right one?

Is secure?

Can I avoid some operations?

Can I optimize something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generating the hash in the client side does not make sense. That way the hash can be used like a password by an attacker. You should create the hash on the server.

Comment: But if I send the clear text, an attacker can simply ready the password..

Comment: Where is the *user table* located, at the server or the device? Why do you calculate four different hashes on the server side? Why don’t you store the password with bcrypt? What’s the purpose of the *serverSideKey*? In the end, it just looks overcomplicated.

Comment: Storing the hash of a raw password is an outdated practice prone to [rainbow table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) attacks. You should only store the hash of a salted password.

Comment: Obviously you should _never_ send authentication tokens over unencrypted connections. If you plan to, the hashing does not help. It is primitive obfuscation that pretends security where there is none. Don't fall for that!

Comment: So I have to send through SSL the clear password and simply store the bcrypt of the password + server key?

Comment: That’s common practice. But what’s the server key for?

Comment: So I only have to do the rest request through a https url with the clear password and store the bcrypt of the password + custom salt? And for the login I'll do a rest call with the clear password and will compare the bcrypt of this password + custom salt and the stored one in the db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, don't do it like that.

Never pass the hash. The hash must be calculated on the server. Else it's just a password.

Only use cryptographic hashes. SHA256 is not one. Use bcrypt, scrypt, or pbkdf2.

It needs to be as simple as possible so you don't make mistakes, and you're complicating it.

Comment: So I only have to do the rest request through a https url with the clear password and store the bcrypt of the password + custom salt? And for the login I'll do a rest call with the clear password and will compare the bcrypt of this password + custom salt and the stored one in the db?

Comment: yup, though the password is not send in the clear with HTTPS, it is encrypted

Comment: And for authentication what do you suggest?
I've to store an api key on the db, return that on login ok, for using as header on the next request?

Comment: @helloimyourmind there are a few approaches, such as OAuth, or see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html